# Count number of weeks product is sold, based on daily sales

Tags: powerbi, calendar, dax, weekday

How to calculate number of weeks that the product is sold (per year), based on daily sales.

There is a daily sales table (millions of entries)

| BookingDate | ProductId | Pieces |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 1 | 10 |
| 01-02-2023 | 1 | 2 |

Product Table

| ProductId | ProductName | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kiwi gold | 0.99 |

I'd like to know how many weeks each product has been active (sold at least once in a week) in a year

| Year | Product | WeeksActive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Kiwi gold | 10 |
| 2023 | Kiwi green | 12 |
| 2022 | Kiwi gold | 50 |

This number is then needed to make further calculations. Is this possible?

(tried: extracted WeekNumber and Year from Booking date, tried creating a new table that holds articles per week per year, but don't know enough to build it)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a DAX solution, but you tagged it for powerquery, so what the heck. Add columns to pull out the month and week. Remove all columns but the two columns and the ProductID. Remove all duplicate rows. Group on year and product ID

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"BookingDate", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year([BookingDate])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Week", each Date.WeekOfYear([BookingDate])),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"ProductId", "Year", "Week"}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"ProductId", "Year"}, {{"Weeks", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

then merge in the name

Comment: Oh I def want the Dax solution! Would actually love to try both

Comment: i can reproduce these steps through the UI, works great. 


2 thigs though, why do we have to remove duplicates? That just means that i sold the same product in the same week multiple times, no? 


With groupings, i think we have to group by Year, WeekNumber,ArticleId, then the count does it's magic

Comment: I remove duplicates so I can count rows. If there are two duplicate rows my it counted twice. You could could count distinct rows and only need one step.  Or group by year, productid, week as you said. Whatever works

Comment: Tnx! How would i do this with a dax formula?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a 1 trick pony.  Someone else will share a DAX version, but not if you mark this as answered. Maybe take that off